# Draw rectangle around nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a lot of nodes placed with tikz. Now I need to draw an rectangle around all these nodes.

I can draw the rectangle manually with

```
\draw [fill=gray!5] (2, -6) rectangle (18, 6.5) 
(2, 6.5) node[below right,fill,draw] {Rectangle Title};
```

All my nodes are named and placed relatively:

```
...
\node [below=5cm of nodeA] (nodeB) {Node B text};
...
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look at the `fit` library.

Comment: Look at  TikZ library `fit` (p.630, pgfmanual)...

Comment: Pick the two nodes, one in the lower left and one in the upper right, and use the `fit` library. This seems to be the best solution but it might be different if we saw your code.

Comment: Some examples for the `fit` library: [how to draw a container box in latex around automata?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75498) [Tikz - How to Draw Boxes Around Set of Nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8896)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let suppose, that your nodes have names. Among them are most outside `northernmost`, `southernmost`, `easternmost` and `westernmost`. In this case, as above comments say, the simple solution is:

- in preamble put TikZ library `fit`
- in your TikZ picture use `\node[draw,inner sep=2mm,label=below:Rectangle Title,fit=(northernmost) (southernmost) (easternmost) (westernmost)] {};`